# Dense roots in french drain

Tags: plumbing

I'm looking for advice on how to get rid of the roots in the french drain on my property.

During the recent exceptionally heavy rains, we've found that the water started seeping from underneath the slab into the basement, which led us to start looking for potential root (hah!) cause. The initial suspicion fell on the drain system around the property. After some digging, we've found the exit of the drain, and it turned out that it is clogged with fairly dense roots that do not seem to budge at all when pulled. Is this a situation that we can DIY ourselves away from?

I'm open to renting a specialized tool, but I am not sure how a drain snake could help with such a dense clog of roots. Any advice welcome!

[image: Roots sticking out of damaged french drain pipe]

Comment: this is how roto-rooter got its name.

Comment: You need professional help and follow up with routine maintenance - rodding once or twice a year. Also, routinely pouring some root killers may help.

Comment: What tools would roto-rooter use to tackle this problem? Is it possible to rent them? I'm still considering my options, "hire a professional" is one of them. "Routinely pouring some root killer" - do you know where should it be poured? As far as I know, I don't have any access to the drain system - I have checked the perimeter of the house and there are no cleanouts / access points / etc (sorry, not sure on the terminology here).

Comment: Well, small correction, I now have access to the drain system through the end of the french drain pictured above, but nothing upstream. After this problem is solved, I plan on extending the drain a bit so that it is possible to install a pop-up drainage emitter - this would serve as the entry to the system, but it'd be at the very bottom of it.